# How to implement Printing function of PDF Document without showing Print Dialog in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprintpreviewdialog

I have seen so many examples of the implementation of the document printing function, but it is the QPrintDialog that is used everywhere, I need the document to immediately go to print after pressing the "Print" button. Are there any solutions?

I will be very grateful for your answers.

Comment: Just use [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) instead of `QPrintDialog.printer()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.